# Encrypting and Decryption Local storage values

Tags: angular, typescript, encryption

In Angular, How to encrypt a value and store it in Local Storage and then Retrieve and Decrypt it.

**Example**

```
    a: Number = 5;
    b: Number = 6;
    c: Number;
    c= a+b;
    localStorage.setItem('result', (this.c)); // I wan to encrypt and store it in local storge here
    localStorage.getItem('result'); // I want to decrypt and get the value
```

Which is the best way and how?

Comment: try to use javascript built-in method for encryption and decryption in base64.
here is a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: @FarhatZaman base64 is not encryption.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are several ways do this but to decide which is best way to do? You need decide that what are trying to achieve with this encryption/decryption? Ideally, you can't secure local storage and it is not recommended to store any sensitive data in local storage. Couple of options to use store encrypted data in locals storage/

- [secure-web-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-web-storage)
- [secure-ls](https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-ls)
- [localstorage-slim](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localstorage-slim) [(tutorial)](https://digitalfortress.tech/js/encrypt-localstorage-data/)
- BASE64 [Encoding/Decoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding). Encoding/Decoding means transforming data from one form to another for transmission or storage purposes.  Transformed data can easily be reversed by anybody. This is not a encryption and can't secure data.

other similar libraries

- [angular-web-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-web-storage)

Comment: Base64 encoding is just that, encoding, not encryption.

Comment: Yes, I did link to encoding/decoding details. May be update details clearly.

Comment: @Drewness when it is done in the browser, encryption is pretty much the same as encoding. The only difference is encryption uses some plain text password to encode the data. But that doesn't make it much more secure.

Comment: encrypting with a static key is not a good option, You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-secure-storage.

Answer (score 4):

Even if there are many replies on the same subject for numerous queries, I wanted to share my ideas nonetheless.

Encryption is one of the solutions in this case, but it is still insufficient to secure local storage if you just encrypt the data and store it there using a shared or application-specific encryption key. This is what has been used in the libraries mentioned in the verified answer

**Here is why.**

Consider the following scenario: you’ve encrypted the user’s login information and saved it locally. When you reload the platform, you’re decrypting the data that’s been written to local storage and marking the user as logged in or logged out. Your website and the platform use a single secure key to encrypt and decrypt, which means only your website knows how to decrypt.

If someone copies data from local storage and pastes it into a separate browser, then visits your site, your website will authenticate the user. Why?
because your website understands how to decode data!
then, what can we do?
It is preferable to generate a special encryption key that is only known by each browser and use that key to encrypt the data.

One method is to utilise the [react-secure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-secure-storage) package, which generates a special encryption key known only to the browser being used.

**Here is how to use it:**

```
yarn add react-secure-storage

npm install react-secure-storage
```

Sample code

```
import { useEffect } from  "react";
import  secureLocalStorage  from  "react-secure-storage";


const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("object", {
            message:  "This is testing of local storage",
        });
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("number", 12);
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("string", "12");
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("boolean", true);
        let value = secureLocalStorage.getItem("boolean");
    }, []);

   return (
        <div>
            This is a sample code
        </div>
    );
}

export  default  App;
```

> NOTE: This library is tested implemented and tested considering react in mind, But if you use it in a way that, you will invoke this library only after you have `window` object, Then this will works for Angular and other frameworks

Answer (score 1):

### Use react-secure-storage as a state with generic types:

As already answered, [react-secure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-secure-storage) is a wonderful way to encrypt data in local storage.

However, it is somewhat limited in its use with Typescirpt, as it only supports the following types:

**String | Object | Number | Boolean**

But not generic types.

To use the localstorage in react with typeScript like a react-state, [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage) is a really useful hook. So I extended this hook with the encryption service of react-secure-storage:

```
import {
    Dispatch,
    SetStateAction,
    useCallback,
    useEffect,
    useState,
} from 'react'

import {useEventCallback, useEventListener} from 'usehooks-ts'
import EncryptionService from "react-secure-storage/src/lib/encryption.ts";

declare global {
    interface WindowEventMap {
        'local-storage': CustomEvent
    }
}

type SetValue<T> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>


export function useSecureLocalStorage<T>(
    key: string,
    initialValue: T,
): [T, SetValue<T>] {

    // Get from local storage then
    // parse stored json or return initialValue
    const readValue = useCallback((): T => {
        // Prevent build error "window is undefined" but keeps working
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            return initialValue
        }

        try {
            // Get encryption from react-secure-storage
            const encryption = new EncryptionService

            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key)

            if (item && encryption.decrypt(item)) {
                return parseJSON(encryption.decrypt(item)) as T
            }
            return initialValue


        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(`Error reading localStorage key “${key}”:`, error)
            return initialValue
        }
    }, [initialValue, key])

    // State to store our value
    // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(readValue)

    // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
    // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
    const setValue: SetValue<T> = useEventCallback(value => {
        // Prevent build error "window is undefined" but keeps working
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            console.warn(
                `Tried setting localStorage key “${key}” even though environment is not a client`,
            )
        }

        try {
            // Allow value to be a function so we have the same API as useState
            const newValue = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value

            // Get encryption from react-secure-storage
            const encryption = new EncryptionService

            // Save to local storage
            window.localStorage.setItem(key, encryption.encrypt(JSON.stringify(newValue)))

            // Save state
            setStoredValue(newValue)

            // We dispatch a custom event so every useLocalStorage hook are notified
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event('local-storage'))
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn(`Error setting localStorage key “${key}”:`, error)
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        setStoredValue(readValue())
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [])

    const handleStorageChange = useCallback(
        (event: StorageEvent | CustomEvent) => {
            if ((event as StorageEvent)?.key && (event as StorageEvent).key !== key) {
                return
            }
            setStoredValue(readValue())
        },
        [key, readValue],
    )

    // this only works for other documents, not the current one
    useEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange)

    // this is a custom event, triggered in writeValueToLocalStorage
    // See: useLocalStorage()
    useEventListener('local-storage', handleStorageChange)

    return [storedValue, setValue]
}

// A wrapper for "JSON.parse()"" to support "undefined" value
function parseJSON<T>(value: string | null): T | undefined {
    try {
        return value === 'undefined' ? undefined : JSON.parse(value ?? '')
    } catch {
        console.log('parsing error on', {value})
        return undefined
    }
}
```

Now you can use react-secure-storage as react-state and the data will be stored encrypted in localstorage:

```
import {useSecureLocalStorage} from "useSecureLocalStorage.ts";


const YourComponent = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useSecureLocalStorage<YourCustomType>("key", defaultValue)

    setData(newValue)
    console.log(data)

    return (
        <div>
           {data} 
        </div>
    )

}    

export default YourComponent
```

---

I hope this is helpful to one or the other. If you have suggestions for improvement or comments please comment below ;)

Comment: Wow, its a really nice implementation on the react-secure-storage, I'll extend this functionality on the library itself. +FYI, You can pass any types to set function of react-secure-storage, it is not limited on the generic types